# How can i know if percona is installed

Tags: mysql, percona

I though it is a silly question but after searching all over internet could not find an answer. 
So how do I check if I have Percona or original MySQL installed on the server?

Comment: try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: Thanx. This works. I also found another way: /etc/init.d/mysql restart shows 'Shutting down MySQL (Percona Server)

Answer (score 6):

```
service mysql status
```

On a centos/fedora based server, this command is a pseudonym for

```
systemctl status mysql
```

it will report

```
mysqld.service - MySQL Percona Server
```

If you have percona installed.  You may need root permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to check is to issue "SHOW PLUGINS" from your mysql client.

If you see anything XTRADB such as XTRADB_READ_VIEW/XTRADB_INTERNAL_HASH_TABLES/XTRADB_RSEG then you know it is Percona Server since they add in XTRADB. That will not be part of Oracle Community.